Miners stuck in the tunnel while water level rises
This is a movie/tv movie I saw when I was about 10, so probably 25-30 years old by now.
All I can remember is that they were in a tunnel (probably miners) both men and women..maybe also children..
Something went wrong and the tunnel started flooding in fast..the miners reason that they would be better of walking further down the tunnel where the roof was higher and wait it out instead of trying to swim up toward the exit.
But the plan didnt work and now they're stuck down there and the water slowly raising...
C'mon! Help me find the title of this movie.

This sounds like Daylight starring Sylvester Stallone. Sly plays Kit Latura, a former New York City Emergency Medical Services Chief, but now works as a cabbie. He attempts to save the day with much of what you describe as happening. This movie is only about 20yo, but it fits your description pretty well. From IMDB (though the link above to Wiki is a lot more descriptive):

Trouble strikes when runaway robbers in a getaway car hit truck full of explosives in the tunnel connecting Manhattan and New Jersey. Survivors are left in a weakened tunnel blocked at both exits. As Kit Latura approaches the tunnel, he see the impact and knows he gotta take action. With time running out, he enters the tunnel through a system of maintenance walkways. Can he get the survivors out before the tunnel fills up?


Hi, Sorry, should have been more clear. This is 80s or maybe even 70s. It's a Cave, probably a miners cave and not in a car tunnel.
